How to filter an calculated metric with values from to separate tables in a blend
I have a blend data from three tables: Google Analytics, with campaigns and sessions, Google Ads, with cost, and Meta Ads with amount spent. I use left join (GA>Google, GA>Meta) and campaign as key.
In my report i have a table with the calculated field: sum(ifnull(cost,0))+sum(ifnull(amount spent, 0).
I want to filter when the calculated field is 0.
I tried using a filter with:
exclued cost is null and exclued amount spent is null
But it didn't work, it breaks the table.
